# Gizmo Movement Script in Raylib with Mouse Interactions to move an entity in 3-D space

Tags: c++

I have a working gizmo movement script made in Raylib that allows me to move an entity (i.e. `entity_in_inspector`) in a 3D space using 6 arrows. Each arrow is rotated at a 90° angle from each other, and when I hover my mouse over an arrow, it turns green and I can change the entity's position in the axis the arrow is rotated.

However, I would like to improve this script and I would appreciate a code review to help me identify any possible improvements or optimizations. If possible I would also like to make the code smaller and more readable.

Here's the code snippet:

```cpp
// Textures
RenderTexture2D renderTexture;
Texture2D texture;
Rectangle rectangle = { screenWidth*.2, screenHeight*.2, texture.width, texture.height };

// Camera
Camera3D scene_camera;

Vector2 mousePosition;
Vector2 mousePositionPrev = GetMousePosition();
Vector3 front;

// ImGui Window Info
float windowWidth;
float windowHeight;
float windowX;
float windowY;

// Gizmo
Model gizmo_arrow_up;
Model gizmo_arrow_down;
Model gizmo_arrow_right;
Model gizmo_arrow_left;
Model gizmo_arrow_forward;
Model gizmo_arrow_backward;

Vector3 gizmo_arrow_up_position;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_down_position;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_right_position;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_left_position;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_forward_position;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_backward_position;

Vector3 gizmo_arrow_up_rotation;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_down_rotation;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_right_rotation;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_left_rotation;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_forward_rotation;
Vector3 gizmo_arrow_backward_rotation;

string up_down = "up-down";
string right_left = "up-down";
string forward_backward = "up-down";

string gizmo_arrow_up_drag_direction = up_down;
string gizmo_arrow_down_drag_direction = up_down;
string gizmo_arrow_right_drag_direction = right_left;
string gizmo_arrow_left_drag_direction = right_left;
string gizmo_arrow_forward_drag_direction = forward_backward;
string gizmo_arrow_backward_drag_direction = forward_backward;


Model gizmo_arrows[] = {
    gizmo_arrow_up,
    gizmo_arrow_down,
    gizmo_arrow_right,
    gizmo_arrow_left,
    gizmo_arrow_forward,
    gizmo_arrow_backward,
};

Vector3 gizmo_arrows_position[] = {
    gizmo_arrow_up_position,
    gizmo_arrow_down_position,
    gizmo_arrow_right_position,
    gizmo_arrow_left_position,
    gizmo_arrow_forward_position,
    gizmo_arrow_backward_position
};

Vector3 gizmo_arrows_rotation[] = {
    gizmo_arrow_up_rotation,
    gizmo_arrow_down_rotation,
    gizmo_arrow_right_rotation,
    gizmo_arrow_left_rotation,
    gizmo_arrow_forward_rotation,
    gizmo_arrow_backward_rotation
};

string gizmo_arrows_drag_directions[] = {
    gizmo_arrow_up_drag_direction,
    gizmo_arrow_down_drag_direction,
    gizmo_arrow_right_drag_direction,
    gizmo_arrow_left_drag_direction,
    gizmo_arrow_forward_drag_direction,
    gizmo_arrow_backward_drag_direction
};


Vector2 GetMouseMove()
{
    static Vector2 lastMousePosition = { 0 };
    Vector2 mousePosition = GetMousePosition();
    Vector2 mouseMove = { mousePosition.x - lastMousePosition.x, mousePosition.y - lastMousePosition.y };
    lastMousePosition = mousePosition;

    return mouseMove;
}

float gizmo_drag_sensitivity_factor = 0.1f;

// Dragging state variables
bool dragging_gizmo = false;
Vector2 mouse_drag_start = { 0, 0 };

float GetModelHeight(Model model) 
{
    BoundingBox modelBBox = GetMeshBoundingBox(model.meshes[0]);
    float modelHeight = modelBBox.max.y - modelBBox.min.y;
    return modelHeight;
}


float GetExtremeValue(const Vector3& a) {
    return std::max(std::max(std::abs(a.x), std::abs(a.y)), std::abs(a.z));
}


bool IsMouseHoveringModel(Model model, Camera camera, Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation)
{
    float x = position.x;
    float y = position.y;
    float z = position.z;

    //std::cout << "X: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << std::endl;

    float extreme_rotation = GetExtremeValue(rotation);

    Matrix matScale = MatrixScale(1, 1, 1);
    Matrix matRotation = MatrixRotate(rotation, extreme_rotation*DEG2RAD);
    Matrix matTranslation = MatrixTranslate(x, y, z);

    Matrix modelMatrix = MatrixMultiply(MatrixMultiply(matScale, matRotation), matTranslation);



    if (IsMouseInRectangle(GetMousePosition(), rectangle))
    {
        Ray ray = { 0 };

        Vector2 pos = { GetMousePosition().x - windowX, GetMousePosition().y - windowY };
        Vector2 realPos = { pos.x * GetScreenWidth()/rectangle.width, pos.y * GetScreenHeight()/rectangle.height };        
        //std::cout << "Position: " << realPos.x << ", " << realPos.y << ", " << std::endl;
        ray = GetMouseRay(realPos, camera);
        RayCollision meshHitInfo = { 0 };


        for (int mesh_i = 0; mesh_i < model.meshCount; mesh_i++)
        {
            meshHitInfo = GetRayCollisionMesh(ray, model.meshes[mesh_i], modelMatrix);
            if (meshHitInfo.hit)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (meshHitInfo.hit) return true;

    }

    return false;
}

int gizmo_arrow_selected;
bool isHoveringGizmo;

void Gizmo()
{
    // Gizmo Arrow Up
    gizmo_arrows[0] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[0] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x, entity_in_inspector->position.y + 6, entity_in_inspector->position.z};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[0] = {0, 0, 0};

    // Gizmo Arrow Down
    gizmo_arrows[1] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[1] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x, entity_in_inspector->position.y - 6, entity_in_inspector->position.z};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[1] = {180, 0, 0};

    // Gizmo Arrow Right
    gizmo_arrows[2] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[2] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x, entity_in_inspector->position.y, entity_in_inspector->position.z + 6};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[2] = {90, 0, 0};

    // Gizmo Arrow Left
    gizmo_arrows[3] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[3] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x, entity_in_inspector->position.y, entity_in_inspector->position.z - 6};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[3] = {-90, 0, 0};

    // Gizmo Arrow Forward
    gizmo_arrows[4] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[4] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x + 6, entity_in_inspector->position.y, entity_in_inspector->position.z};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[4] = {0, 0, -90};

    // Gizmo Arrow Backward
    gizmo_arrows[5] = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
    gizmo_arrows_position[5] = {entity_in_inspector->position.x - 6, entity_in_inspector->position.y, entity_in_inspector->position.z};
    gizmo_arrows_rotation[5] = {0, 0, 90};


    // Position Update
    for (int arrow_i = 0; arrow_i < size(gizmo_arrows); arrow_i++)
    {
        Color color1;

        if (!dragging_gizmo)
        {
            isHoveringGizmo = IsMouseHoveringModel(gizmo_arrows[arrow_i], scene_camera, gizmo_arrows_position[arrow_i], gizmo_arrows_rotation[arrow_i]);
            
            if (isHoveringGizmo)
            {
                color1 = GREEN;
                gizmo_arrow_selected = arrow_i;
            }
            else
            {
                color1 = RED;
                gizmo_arrow_selected == -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            color1 = RED;
            gizmo_arrow_selected == -1;
        }

        if (IsMouseButtonDown(MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON))
        {
            if (isHoveringGizmo)
            {
                if (!dragging_gizmo)
                {
                    mouse_drag_start = GetMousePosition();
                    dragging_gizmo = true;
                }
            }
            if (dragging_gizmo)
            {
                Vector2 mouse_drag_end = GetMousePosition();
                if ( gizmo_arrow_selected == 0 || gizmo_arrow_selected == 1 )
                {
                    float delta_y = (mouse_drag_end.y - mouse_drag_start.y) * gizmo_drag_sensitivity_factor;
                    gizmo_arrow_up_position.y -= delta_y;
                }

                else if ( gizmo_arrow_selected == 2 || gizmo_arrow_selected == 3 )
                {
                    float delta_z = ((mouse_drag_end.x - mouse_drag_start.x) + (mouse_drag_end.y - mouse_drag_start.y)) * gizmo_drag_sensitivity_factor;
                    gizmo_arrow_up_position.z -= delta_z;
                }
                
                else if ( gizmo_arrow_selected == 4 || gizmo_arrow_selected == 5 )
                {
                    float delta_x = (mouse_drag_end.x - mouse_drag_start.x) * gizmo_drag_sensitivity_factor;
                    gizmo_arrow_up_position.x += delta_x;
                }

                // Update drag start position
                mouse_drag_start = mouse_drag_end;
            }
        }
        else dragging_gizmo = false;

        float extreme_rotation = GetExtremeValue(gizmo_arrows_rotation[arrow_i]);
        DrawModelEx(gizmo_arrows[arrow_i], gizmo_arrows_position[arrow_i], gizmo_arrows_rotation[arrow_i], extreme_rotation, {1,1,1}, color1);
    }
    
    entity_in_inspector->position.x = gizmo_arrow_up_position.x-entity_in_inspector->scale.x*6;
    entity_in_inspector->position.y = gizmo_arrow_up_position.y-entity_in_inspector->scale.y*6;
    entity_in_inspector->position.z = gizmo_arrow_up_position.z-entity_in_inspector->scale.z*6;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Group related data into a `struct`

You have several pieces of data for every arrow. Instead of creating an array for each individual thing, create a `struct` that groups all the data belonging to a vector, and then create an array out of that `struct`:

```
struct Arrow {
    Model model;
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 rotation;
    string drag_directions;
};

Arrow arrows[6];
```

Then at the start of `Gizmo()`, you could write:

```
arrows[0].model = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");
arrows[0].position = {entity_in_inspector->position.x, entity_in_inspector->position.y + 6, entity_in_inspector->position.z};
arrows[0].rotation = {0, 0, 0};
arrows[0].directions = up_down;
```

Or more concisely:

```
arrows[0] = {
    LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj"),
    entity_in_inspector->position + Vector3{0, 6, 0};
    {0, 0, 0},
    up_down,
};
```

## Initializing arrays

You initialize each of your arrays by *copying* the values of other variables into it. But many of the variables you are copying don't have any meaningful value yet. All the `Model`s are empty, the positions and rotations are not initialized. Only the strings containing directions have values.

Then you do the real initialization at the start of `Gizmo()`. But it looks like this function is going to be called many times. It would be much nicer to initialize the array once. But that only works if the contents won't change. But some thing are not necessary anyway. For example:

- The model. Why load the same model for each arrow direction? You only need to load the model once.
- The position of the `entity_in_inspector`. Consider only storing the relative position in the array, and calculte the absolute position inside `Gizmo()` when needed.
- The drag direction strings. They are not used at all in your code. They also look wrong to me, because all directions are set to `"up-down"`.

```
struct Arrow {
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 rotation;
};

static const Arrow arrows[] = {
    {{0, +6, 0}; {  0, 0,   0}},
    {{0, -6, 0}; {180, 0,   0}},
    {{0, 0, +6}; { 90, 0,   0}},
    {{0, 0, -6}; {-90, 0,   0}},
    {{+6, 0, 0}; {  0, 0, -90}},
    {{-6, 0, 0}; {  0, 0,  90}},
};

void Gizmo() {
    static model = LoadModel("assets/models/gizmo/arrow.obj");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(arrows); ++i) {
        Color color1;
        …
        auto position = entity_in_inspector->position + arrows[i].position;
        isHoveringGizmo = IsMouseHoveringModel(model, scene_camera,
                                               position, arrows[i].rotation);
        …
        DrawModelEx(model, position, arrows[i].rotation, extreme_rotation, {1,1,1}, color1);
    }

    entity_in_inspector->position = gizmo_arrow_up_position
                                    - entity_in_inspector->scale * 6;
}
```

## Make more use of vector types

Avoid looking at the `.x`, `.y` and `.z` members of `Vector3` variables, and instead make use of the fact that you can add and subtract other `Vector3`s, that you can multiply by other vectors and scalars, and that there are many functions available that can directly work on them. This saves a lot of typing, reduces the chance of mistakes, and might even make the program more efficient.

You can make vectors out of things that currently are not vectors, like `windowWidth`/`windowHeight` and `windowX`/`windowY`.